# I cannot get post.content to work in Jekyll if else statement

Tags: jekyll, liquid, blogs

I have a blog. On the main page I list 10 blog posts with a brief description.  Pagination is provided by `jekyll-paginate-v2`.  After an import from Wordpress, there are three possible locations for the description, each processed in order.

```
  {% for post in paginator.posts %}
     <article>
        {% if post.description %}
          {{ post.description }}..
        {% elsif post.meta._yoast_wpseo_metadesc %}
          {{ post.meta._yoast_wpseo_metadesc }}..
        {% else %}
          {{ post.content | markdownify | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}..
        {% endif %}<a href="{{ post.url }}" title="{{ post.title }}">Read More &raquo;</a>
    </article>
 {% endfor %}
```

This is not working, no content shows up if the first two do not exist.

```
{{ post.content | markdownify | strip_html | truncatewords: 50 }}..
```

If I replace `post.content` with `post.excerpt` I don't get any content either.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you sure you have posts in paginator.posts? If statements looks ok, I try this with site.posts and this is working fine. Also try check `post.content` outside the if statement.

Comment: Thank you. That worked.